# Input background color change when disabled/enabled

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I have an input inside my `<td>` and it is taking some background (greyish) but I don't want that. I want it to have a transparent background, like my `row` is having a green background, but input is not having that. How to change that?

Comment: Please include your code and explain through there where the issue exists, otherwise it would be extremely difficult to provide a relevant answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS for normal(enable) input

```
input{background-color: transparent;}
```

CSS for disabled input

```
input[disabled]{background-color: red;}
```

Comment: If you still need any help then please provide your code.

Comment: no thanks, it worked, the issue was implementing it in tailwind, but it's solved now